# Convert SetPixel to SetPixels32

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to convert my code which has SetPixel to SetPixels32. Below is my code with SetPixel

```
for (int x = 0; x < _brush.width; x++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < _brush.height; y++)
    {
        data = (pixelXOffset + x) + (pixelYOffset + y) * _templateDirtMask.width;

        if (data > 0 && data < pixels.Length)
        {
            Color pixelDirt = _brush.GetPixel(x, y);
            Color pixelDirtMask = _templateDirtMask.GetPixel(pixelXOffset + x, pixelYOffset + y);
   
            pixels[data] = new Color(0, pixelDirtMask.g * pixelDirt.g, 0);
        }
                    
    }
}

_templateDirtMask.SetPixels(pixels);
_templateDirtMask.Apply();
```

Then this is my code for SetPixels32

```
    for (int x = 0; x < _brush.width; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < _brush.height; y++)
        {
            int arrElement = (pixelXOffset + x) + ((pixelYOffset + y) * heightScreenRes);

            if (arrElement > 0 && arrElement < dirtMaskArr.Length)
            {
                Color32 pixelDirt = brushPixels[x + (y * 32)];

                Color32 pixelDirtMask = dirtMaskArr[arrElement];

                double pixelDirtMaskA = pixelDirtMask.g / 255.0;

                double pixelDirtA = pixelDirt.g / 255.0;

                double a = (pixelDirtMaskA * pixelDirtA) * 255;

                dirtMaskArr[arrElement] = new Color32(0, Convert.ToByte(a), 0, 255);
            }
        }
    }

    _templateDirtMask.SetPixels32(dirtMaskArr);
    _templateDirtMask.Apply(false);
```

My problem is it's not working.

Comment: What does `it's not working` mean exactly? And in general why do you first divide both values by `255` just to then again multiply them? If those are just the same `float` values between `0` and `1` like in your upper example then of course dividing them by `255` makes them too small ...

Comment: Is there a specific reason why to do this conversion at all? The upper one should be as fine to use, just move out the `GetPixel` calls into a single `GetPixels` and rather access via indices which would be more performant

Comment: @derHugo The reason is I'll test to see who is more faster between SetPixels vs SetPixels32

Comment: I think if you already have `byte` / `Color32` data then probably this should be faster ... however if this mans you have to do more operations for your calculations you probably mitigate this to some extend ...